# How to get list of files by their Timestamp attribute present in Digital Signatures tab of a file using PowerShell Script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, signing, digital-certificate

I want the list of files present inside multiple folders whose **Timestamp** attribute value is set to "**Not Available**" which is present in **Digital Signatures** tab, how can i get the list of files using PowerShell Script?

[image]

I tried using **$_.VersionInfo** property but it only access the attribute from details tab but i want to access the attribute present inside Digital Signatures tab.
Any help on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: The `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` cmdlet gets information about the Authenticode signature for a file. If the file is not signed, the information is retrieved, but the fields are blank.

Comment: I tried using Get-AuthenticodeSignature cmdlet but some how it is not able to give me the list of files which are not signed.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem * -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {  (get-AuthenticodeSignature $_.FullName) } | Where-Object { $_.Status -ne 'Valid' } | ForEach-Object { '{0} {1}' -f $_.Status, $_.Path }`